# how to autostart php-fpm on mac

Tags: php, macos, launchctl

i wanna install the nginx and php on my mac(Yosemite10.10.5).***but the php-fpm can't autostart when i restart the mac.***

step1,install nginx by brew

===>success, i can visit the http://localhost/index.html

step2,set the nginx service autostart as follow

```
sudo chown root:wheel/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx
sudo chmod u+s/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/opt/nginx/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

step3,test the autostart func,see the pic.

===>success

step4,install php5.4 by brew

===>success

step4,set the php54 autostart as follow

```
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/opt/php54/sbin/php-fpm
sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/opt/php54/sbin/php-fpm
cp /usr/local/opt/php54/homebrew.mxcl.php54.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgets
```

step5,test the autostart funcs

===>***failed,and nothing happened.see the pic.***

step6,i guess that's the permission problem,so i typed as follow and success.

```
sudo launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php54.plist
```

so, i did the step4 as nginx to avoid the permission problem, but the result is failed. any help will be appreciate.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50u71.jpg)